# Python date in seconds UNIX format

Tags: python, windows, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

Sup guys! I want to know how to get current day (only day) in seconds UNIX format. I get that time.time() shows me current time but i want to get period 00:00 %h%s of current day. Help plsss

I need it to compare date of modofication folder with current day in seconds.

Comment: I do not understand what are you looking for. `time.time()` gives you the seconds from epoch, so the normal UNIX format. Else use `datetime` module (e.g. `.now()`) and get the hours, minutes and seconds. From there I think you can calculate how many seconds passed from midnight (but this is very different from the title of the question).

Comment: Unix time is seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC date and does not take leap seconds into account - you can get the start of the day by flooring current Unix time to multiples of the seconds in a day. Let `t = time.time()`, then that would be `t_day_start = int(t) - int(t)%86400`.